# Select item in angular selectbox using selenium

Tags: c#, angular, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make a selection in a dropdown using selenium.
The selectbox is not a html type of 'select' but is using angular so it is a 'mat-select' html-tag.

I simplified my code to get this to work but could not get it to work, this is my code right now:

```
var q = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("mat-select"));
new SelectElement(q).SelectByText("My List Value");
```

When I run this code I get:

```
Element should have been select but was mat-select
```

How do I solve this? I tried using SendKeys but since "My List Value" has spaces, the space triggers the selectbox to open or close and it won't select the correct value. Then I read about SelectByText but that seems to require a normal '' but I only have a ''.

Here is the html of the select:

```
<div class="mat-form-field-infix">
    <mat-select _ngcontent-qpv-c46="" class="mat-select ng-tns-c12-118 ng-pristine ng-valid mat-select-empty ng-star-inserted ng-touched" role="listbox" id="mat-select-5" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="mat-form-field-label-41" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="mat-select-trigger" aria-hidden="true" cdk-overlay-origin="">
            <div class="mat-select-value">
                <!---->
                <span class="mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-c12-118 ng-star-inserted">&nbsp;</span>
                <!---->
            </div>
            <div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper">
                <div class="mat-select-arrow"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---->
    </mat-select>
    <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper">
        <!---->
        <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c24-117 mat-empty mat-form-field-empty ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-41" for="mat-select-5" aria-owns="mat-select-5">
            <!----><!---->
            <mat-label _ngcontent-qpv-c46="" class="ng-star-inserted">Properties</mat-label>
            <!----><!---->
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

All the options are missing in the html? I know c# but not angular so this looks a bit funny to me. Have not tried to click because I don't know how to find them when I can't even see them myself.

When I click on the select all items appear in some magical angular way...

Comment: can you, please, provide a piece of the page source? 
did you try to interact with the elements by clicking on them instead of using SelectElement?

Comment: Hi @Marek.  I have not tried to click since I don't know how to find the items when they are not there? I have added the html above.

Comment: is this the full html code, also for the options you want to select?

Comment: Yes. And that's the problem. I can't see them in the html. But when I click on the select-box they just appear and are added to the dom. I am guessing it is some "Angular-magic" behind that..

Comment: that's the point, isn't? write the code for the scenario you just mention - wait for the page to load, click on the select-box, wait for the options to appear and then click on the requested one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium doesn't provide methods for interacting with `mat-select`. You need to write a custom program for Selenium to interact with a `mat-select`.

Here is an example of how to select a `mat-select` option with Selenium using C#:

```
IWebElement field = driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector('mat-select'));

// Click to open the dropdown.
field.Click();

// Query for options in the DOM. These exist outside of the mat-select component.
IReadOnlyList<WebElement> options = driver.FindElements(By.cssSelector("mat-option"));

// Find the option with the text that matches the one you are looking for.
options.First(element => element.GetText() == "My List Value")
     // Click it to select it.
    .Click();
```

You will probably want to wrap this up in a re-usable method of some sort.

Comment: The question is tagged C# so answers should be in C#.

Comment: @JeffC Oh, woops, didn't see that it was tagged. I edited the code to be in C#, thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help! Both answers worked but found this a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you got the error is because `SelectElement()` can only be used with an HTML SELECT element. The `mat-select` (and some other elements) may be formatted to *look* like a dropdown but they are not SELECT dropdown elements. Because of this, we aren't going to be able to use `SelectElement()` but there are ways around this.

The simplest way I've found is to find the `mat-select` element (typically by ID) and click it to open the dropdown. Then click the desired option using an XPath that contains the expected string. The code below shows this but the second locator is a guess because the HTML you provided didn't show the dropdown options. If you update the HTML to show this, I can update and test the locator but even if you don't, this should point you in the right direction.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("mat-select-5"))).Click();
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'My List Value')]"))).Click();
```

I added waits just to be safe. They may not be needed.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("mat-select-5")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'My List Value')]")).Click();
```

---

I'm assuming you are going to use this more than once. In that case, I would write a method that takes in the desired option and selects it.

```
public void SelectProperty(string propertyName)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("mat-select-5"))).Click();
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath($"//span[contains(text(),'{propertyName}')]"))).Click();
}
```

and call it like...

```
SelectProperty("My List Value");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Both solutions worked but I found the solutions from garbear a bit easier and also useful with the options list.

Comment: I'm confused... what is it about his that's easier? His is 5 lines of code where mine is 2 or 3 (if you want the wait). Also his will be slower since he's not using the desired text in the locator and is instead looping through all values until the correct one is found.